# GLS (generalized least squares) on times series with R correlation problem

Tags: r, regression, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

I have a lot of variables like Money supply, GDP and CPI. I have used a multiple linear model but the data are too correlated, so I tested with the `glm`. But I do not know how to test the residues and how to know if the model is good. I used R package "nlme" with `gls` function like this :

```
m <- gls(M2~IPC+PIBRHH+PIBRH+PIBNHH+PIBNH, correlation=corAR1())
```

I used AR(1) correlation but I don't know how I choose between AR, ARMA or other, and how to detect their parameters.

Please if someone can help me thanks in advance because this is my final thesis and I am very late I can not move forward.

- **M2** : Money supply
- **IPC** : consumer price index
- **PIBRHH** : Real gross domestic product excluding hydrocarbon
- **PIBRH** : Real gross domestic product hydrocarbon
- **PIBNHH** : Nominal gross domestic product excluding hydrocarbons
- **PIBNH** : Nominal gross domestic product hydrocarbon

[Here are the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19RRh0MoASAi80_bPk9puYraWFrWmrs3nHFh58ylpJ-E).

Comment: You want an univariate model with exogenous variables or a multivariate time series model?